# count all possible paths of length n in an undirected graph with use of dynamic programming

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given is an infinitely large grid graph. Use dynamic programming to calculate the number of possible paths
of a given length n from a given start node, so that fjor every path applies: 
a) no vertex may be visited twice within it
 and 
b) never to go down an edge
[image: example of lattice graph for paths of length 2]

I found out, that the number of possible paths corresponds to the row sums of the binomial coefficent, times 2 minus the center row, but if n is bigger than 3 other paths emerge which I struggle to include in my dynamic programming solution

Comment: If you have a formula, you don't need to use dunamic programming.

Comment: I know, but I am required to find the solution by using dynamic programming

Comment: This question is somewhat familiar. @Apass.Jack hope I didn't help anyone cheat (possibly some competition?)